# Sum of values in 2D vector

Tags: arrays, clojure

I have a 2D vector that looks like this

```
[[1917 2850]
 [1623 34]
 [1917 300]]
```

I want to get the totals of the second value for all of the values where the first value is the same. So it will produce a result like this

```
 [[1917 3150]
 [1623 34]]
```

How can I do this in Clojure? I thought maybe I could add into sorted-set but I'm not sure this is best.

Comment: `(vec (reduce (fn [acc [l r]] (update acc l (fnil + 0) r)) {} data))` , but really, you should read some introduction to clojure first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it step by step:

Using `sort-by` + `partition-by`...

```clj
(->> [[1917 2850]
      [1623 34]
      [1917 300]]
     ;; sort by first element
     (sort-by first)
     ;; split when first element changes
     (partition-by (comp identity first))
     ;; for each partition, take first element of first row
     ;; as key, and sum up second element of each row as value
     (mapv (fn [xs]
             [(ffirst xs)
              (apply + (map second xs))])))
;; => [[1623 34]
;;     [1917 3150]]
```

...or use `group-by`

```
(->> [[1917 2850]
      [1623 34]
      [1917 300]]
     ;; group by first element
     (group-by first)
     ;; for each group, take the group key
     ;; and sum up second element of each row in the group
     (mapv (fn [[g xs]]
             [g (apply + (map second xs))])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up a bit at these books & websites:

- http://clojure.org
- https://www.braveclojure.com/
- https://pragprog.com/book/roclojure/getting-clojure

and [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet).  I would start off with `group-by`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def data
  [[1917 2850]
   [1623 34]
   [1917 300]] )

(group-by first data) => 
    {1917 [[1917 2850] 
           [1917 300]], 
     1623 [[1623 34]]}
```